# Joining functions together - cleaner code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to shorten my code. I need to add about 15 more functions which all do the same thing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.map-highligh').maphilight({

    });

    //north roll over
    $('#hilightlink').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#north').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $('#north').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    //Wellington roll over
    $('#hilightlink-wel').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#wellington').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $('#wellington').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

});
```

Comment: For the best shot at making the code clean, we'd need to see your HTML so we can see if there are DOM relationships or class names we can suggest or use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bit of composition to clean up the code.

```
function makeTrigger(id, eventName) {
    return function(e) {
        $('#' + id).trigger(eventName);
    };
}

function prevent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

$('#hilightlink')
.mouseover(makeTrigger("north", "mouseover"))
.mouseout(makeTrigger("north", "mouseout"))
.click(prevent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rethink your UI for this one, but you could do something like this:

```
function mouseBind(bound, affected) {
   $('#' + bound)
      .mouseover(function () {
         $('#' + affected).mouseover();
      })
      .mouseout(function () {
         $('#' + affected).mouseout();
      })
      .click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); })
   ;
}

mouseBind('hilightlink', 'north');
mouseBind('hilightlink-wel', 'wellington');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function without changes in HTML code:

```
function bind_block(button, element) {
  button.mouseover(function(e) {
    element.mouseover();
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    element.mouseout();
  }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
}

bind_block($('#hilightlink'), $('#north'));
bind_block($('#hilightlink-wel'), $('#wellington'));
```

If you need to bind this events for 15 different elements, it's better to use CSS classes for that. Please provide your HTML to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.rollOver = function(selector) {
    this.on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) { $(selector).trigger(e.type); });
    this.on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    return this;
}
$('#hilightlink').rollOver('#north');
$('#hilightlink-wel').rollOver('#wellington');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what DOM relationships we could exploit to use that to advantage, I'd put the data in a table and iterate over the table so there's only one copy of the code and you can add/remove/modify identifiers without changing the executing code:

```
var hoverItems = [
    "highlightlink", "north",
    "highlightlink-wel", "wellington"
];

for (var i = 0; i < hoverItems.length; i+= 2) {
    (function(item$) {
        $("#" + hoverItems[i]).hover(function() {
            item$.mouseover();
        }, function() {
            item$.mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
    })($(hoverItems[i+1]));
}
```

Or, a slightly different way, using a lookup table:

```
var hoverItems = {
    "highlightlink": "north",
    "highlightlink-wel": "wellington"
};

$("#" + Object.keys(hoverItems).join(", #")).hover(function() {
    $("#" + hoverItems[this.id]).mouseover();
}, function() {
    $("#" + hoverItems[this.id]).mouseout();
}).click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

This second method requires ES5 or an [ES5 shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for the `Object.keys()` method.

To add more items with either one of these methods, just add more items to the data table - you don't write one new line of executing code.